# How can I display the same reviews under all products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shop where every single jacket has a unique pattern, so every product is different and for every product I just have one piece.

Still, I would like to have reviews under my products. 
Is it possible to somehow show the same reviews under all products?

After all, they are the same, they just have different patterns. 
So for example if I put in a new product it will still have all the reviews like all the other products? Any hint is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**EDIT**: Someone in another forum said:

> Reviews are comments. After saving a comment action_hook wp_insert_comment starts. 
>   You could use this to post the same comment under all products. To select all products you would need something that all products have in common.

How would I do this practically, any tips or steps? What would would I need to learn/read?

Thanks for any hints.